# If the subspace $A$ of a metric space $B$ is homeomorphic to a metric space $C$, then $C$ is the subspace of a metric space homeomorphic to $B$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In my proof to an exercice, I used this lemma :

> If the subspace $A$ of a metric space $B$ is homeomorphic to a metric space $C$, then $C$ is the subspace of a metric space homeomorphic to $B$

I think it's true and I think I've proved it, but I want to double check and couldn't find anything on the internet...

My proof goes roughly like this : We can add elements to $C$ so that we get a topological space $D$ homeomorphic to $B$. But since $B$ is metrizable, so is $D$.

Does it hold?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well as $C$ is homeomorphic to $A$ it is certainly a subspace of itself, which then is homeomorphic to $A$, right?

Comment: Sorry, It's edited. $B$ in the stead of $A$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** The counterexample below makes assumptions that haven't been specified in the question: that the desired extension commutes with the homeomorphisms.

See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433835/extending-a-partially-defined-metric-on-a-metrizable-space) for a proper answer (and question!).

---

The answer is No. In fact the lemma is plain wrong and here is a counterexample:
Take $B$ a converging sequence and $A$ the sequence  minus the limit point. Then we can have $C$ a discrete space. $C$ can't be extended to get something homeomorphic to $B$

Answer (score 0):

Your "proof" is not a proof. It's the *idea* of a proof. It's a good idea, and worth pursuing further, but so far, it's just that. To actually prove the statement, you need to

1. Define $D$.
2. Define the metric on $D$.
3. Prove that the metric, applied on $C$, is the same as the original metric on $C$ (depending on how you perform point 2, this part may be trivial).
4. Prove that $D$ is homeomorphic to $B$. To do that, you will have to define a homeomorphism.

**Hint**: maybe try to construct $D$ simply by taking $C$, and adding to it all elements that are in $B$ but not in $A$.

Comment: Yeah, it's only a sketch (thus the 'roughly'). But can I get away by constructing $D$ and its topology (such as its open sets are in bijection with those of $B$) without defining a metric on it?

Comment: @Frousse How can you know what open sets of $D$ are if you don't know what the metric on $D$ is?

Comment: $D$ is defined as a topological space containing $C$ and its open sets in bijection with those of $B$.

Comment: @Frousse But $D$ must also be a metric space. It must have a metric.

Comment: Sure, but since it has the same open sets of $B$, it's homeomorphic to it. And a topological space homeomorphic to a metric space is also a metric space, no?

Comment: @Frousse Well... no. A topological space without a metric is not a metric space, period. They are two (connected, but) different structures. You can, trivially easily, *define* a metric on the topological space that is homeomorphic to a metric space, but once you do, you have constructed a different structure, i.e. a metric space, over the same set over which previously, only a topological space was defined.

Comment: That's a very good point. And after spending 2 weeks trying to prove the statement, I've found a counterexample... Take $B$ a converging sequence and $A$ the sequence  minus the limit point. Then we can have $C$ a discrete space. $C$ can't be extended to get something homeomorphic to $B$...

Comment: @Frousse That's not a counterexample. In the lemma, it is assumed that $C$ is homeomorphic to $B$. Since $B$ is not a discrete space, $C$ cannot be a discrete space.

Comment: $C$ is assumed homeomorphic to $A$ , not $B$

Comment: Do you validate that it's a counterexample?

Comment: @Frousse It is not. Just take $C$, add a point, and make it a limit point of the sequence. $C$ is then extended into something homeomorphic to $B$.

Comment: Ok, here is an example: Take $B$ the elements of the sequence $3, 3.1, 3.14, \ldots , \pi$ with the Euclidean metric. Take $A$ as $B$ without $\pi$. Since $A$ has got no 'nontrivial' converging sequences, then it's homeomorphic to a metric space of same cardinality and embedded with the discrete metric : $C$. How would you add a limit point to $C$ to get something homeomorphic to $B$ ?

Comment: OK, first of all, we know that $C=\{f(3), f(3.1), \dots\}$, where $f$ is the homeomorphism between $A$ and $C$, right? Now, take $C'$ to be $C\cup \{x_0\}$, where $x_0\notin C$. Now define the basis of topology of $C'$ to be all the open sets of $C$ **plus** the sets $C\cup\{x_0\}, \{f(3.1), f(3.14), \dots\}\cup\{x_0\}, f(3.14, f(3.141), \dots\}\cup\{x_0\}, \{f(3.141), f(3.1415), \dots\}\cup\{x_0\}$

Comment: Adding these sets, it is easy to show that the mapping

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)&\text{if }x\neq \pi\\ x_0&\text{if }x=\pi\end{cases}$$ is a homeomorphism mapping from $B$ to $C'$.

Comment: But is $C'$ metrizable in such a way that the elements of $C$ preserve their discrete metric between each other? Because $C$ is embedded with the discrete metric, the sequence $f(3),f(3.1), \ldots$ is not even Cauchy. In $C'$ you need that sequence to be converging, which is impossible.

Comment: That sequence needs to be converging because in $B$, the sequence $3, 3.1, \ldots$ converges; and homeomorphism preserves converging sequences.

Comment: @Frousse Define the metric on $C'$ as follows:
$$d(x_1, x_2) = \begin{cases}|x_1-x_2|&\text{if } x_1, x_2\in\mathbb R\\ \pi - x_2 &\text{if } x_1=x_0\\ \end{cases}$$

Comment: In this metric, the mapping $g$ preserves distances, so it is not only a homeomorphism, it's an isometry - i.e., a metric space isomorphism. Also, in $C'$, the sequence $f(3), f(3.1), f(3.14), \dots$ converges, and it converges to $g(\pi)$.

Comment: A general tip. You are very quick do declare things as impossible, and overall use definitive statements far too loosely. When expressing yourself mathematically, try to use definitive statements only for things you can prove to be true. Otherwise, try using language that shows you are only expressing your opinion. So, don't say that it is *impossible* for the sequence $f(3),f(3.1),\dots$ to converge, unless you have *proof* that that is so. Otherwise, say something like "I can't see how this sequence could possibly converge".

Comment: That's a very good tip. Do you agree with this statement? : $C$ is embedded with the discrete metric : $\forall x_1, x_2 \in \{3, 3.1, \ldots \}$ $$d_C(x_1,x_2) = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{if } x_1 \neq x_2 \\ 0 &\text{if } x_1 = x_2\\ \end{cases} $$

Comment: Also this statement : $C$ is a subspace of $C'$ then $\forall x_1,x_2 \in C$ : $$d_{C'}(x_1, x_2) = d_C(x_1, x_2)$$

Comment: @Frousse The first statement is incorrect. In my argument, I used the standard euclidean metric for $C$, that is, $d(x_1, x_2)=|x_1-x_2|$.

Comment: Sure, but the lemma (which I believe to be wrong) has to work for any $C$ homeomorphic to $A$. I chose to define $C$ precisely that way to give a counterexample and refute the claim ^^. Do you agree that $C$, the way I defined it, is homeomorphic to $A$ ? Can you still construct a metric space $C'$ that has $C$ as a subspace and that is homeomorphic to $B$ ?

Comment: @Frousse Ah, now I see what you mean. You're correct, I think. But the lemma *would* hold if $A$ is not only homeomorphic, but also isometric to $C$.

Comment: Alright, that settles it. Is it fine with you  to write another post, or edit this one, to explain what's  wrong with my attempt at proving the lemma and include the counterexample, so to close the discussion?

Comment: @Frousse Of course, that would be perfect

Comment: Great. Sorry for the inconvenience.